# Nodejs Express Chain of Invocation Unclear

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying this code from: 
[server-side-cache-express](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/server-side-cache-express?path=server.js:51:2)

The code part I am focused is:

```
var cache = (duration) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    let key = '__express__' + req.originalUrl || req.url
    let cachedBody = mcache.get(key)
    if (cachedBody) {
      res.send(cachedBody)
      return
    } else {
      res.sendResponse = res.send
      res.send = (body) => {
        mcache.put(key, body, duration * 1000);
        res.sendResponse(body)
      }
      next()
    }
  }
}

app.get('/', cache(10), (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there', date: new Date()})
  }, 5000) //setTimeout was used to simulate a slow processing request
})
```

What I do not understand is: how come that the res.render invokes the res.send? And if so, isn't there a loop because res.sendResponse(body) in turn is an alias to  res.send? The code is working but it is just that i can't fully explain it.

thanks lot.

Comment: Ok maybe i have understood: since res.sendResponse = res.send is copy by value and since res.send is afterwards redefined then calling res.sendResponse does not go in a loop, right? Also res.render calls (the last definition of) res.send, right?